# Access youtube API v3 in faster way

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using `youtube API v3` in PHP. There is already library available for php.
There is two way to access it.

1- use pre php library and access it.
2- acces direct from URL (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/).

What is the best and faster way to access youtube api.
Thanks.

Comment: 1 still uses 2 so how can we answer this

Comment: @Dagon But there is too many code in first setp. I think it slow down isn't it ?
Because running a lot of code is slower than accessing directly.
I confused about this.

Comment: then write your own code

Comment: @Dagon ok, thanks but what is preferable way ?
Any recommendation from API developer ?

Comment: its utterly up to you

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: personally I like the client library's they are developed mainly by googles and they almost always work and use best practices.   While you can create your own library sometimes its better not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Best and faster way I like is access direct from URL (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/). Main issue is quota exceeded quickly if you call video id info like duration, views, likes, dislikes. To resolve quota issue you can create multiple projects and 1 API key in each project then randomly use all API keys like.

```
$api = array("API key # 1", "API key # 2" ,"API key # 3");
$rand_keys = array_rand($api, 1);
$usage = $api[$rand_keys];
```

For each request new key will be used. Better way to avoid any downtime.